# How to dynamically process payment after an order is created using ajax call in woo commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, hook-woocommerce

I want to process payment after creating an order using Ajax call in woocommerce. I have used below script but payment is not processing.

**AJAX Call Click On Place order**

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'checkout_billing_email_js_ajax' );
function checkout_billing_email_js_ajax() {
    // Only on Checkout
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $(document).on("click", "#place_order" ,function(e) {    
            $.ajax({
                type:    'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                data: {
                    'action': 'ajax_order',
                    'fields': $('form.checkout').serializeArray(),
                    'user_id': <?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result); // For testing (to be removed)
                },
                error:   function(error) {
                    console.log(error); // For testing (to be removed)
                }
            });
        });
    });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

**Call Back Function**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_order', 'submited_ajax_order_data');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_order', 'submited_ajax_order_data' );
function submited_ajax_order_data() {
global $woocommerce;
    if( isset($_POST['fields']) && ! empty($_POST['fields']) ) {
        $order    = new WC_Order();
        $cart     = WC()->cart;
        $checkout = WC()->checkout;
        $wc_gateways      = new WC_Payment_Gateways();
        $payment_gateways = $wc_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();
        $payment_method=$order->get_payment_method_title();

        $data     = [];

        // Loop through posted data array transmitted via jQuery
        foreach( $_POST['fields'] as $values ){
            // Set each key / value pairs in an array
            $data[$values['name']] = $values['value'];
        }

        $cart_hash          = md5( json_encode( wc_clean( $cart->get_cart_for_session() ) ) . $cart->total );
        $available_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();

        // Loop through the data array
        foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
            // Use WC_Order setter methods if they exist
            if ( is_callable( array( $order, "set_{$key}" ) ) ) {
                $order->{"set_{$key}"}( $value );

            // Store custom fields prefixed with wither shipping_ or billing_
            } elseif ( ( 0 === stripos( $key, 'billing_' ) || 0 === stripos( $key, 'shipping_' ) )
                && ! in_array( $key, array( 'shipping_method', 'shipping_total', 'shipping_tax' ) ) ) {
                $order->update_meta_data( '_' . $key, $value );
            }
        }

        $order->set_created_via( 'checkout' );
        $order->set_cart_hash( $cart_hash );
        $order->set_customer_id( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_customer_id', isset($_POST['user_id']) ? $_POST['user_id'] : '' ) );
        $order->set_currency( get_woocommerce_currency() );
        $order->set_prices_include_tax( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_prices_include_tax' ) );
        $order->set_customer_ip_address( WC_Geolocation::get_ip_address() );
        $order->set_customer_user_agent( wc_get_user_agent() );
        $order->set_customer_note( isset( $data['order_comments'] ) ? $data['order_comments'] : '' );
       // $order->set_payment_method( isset( $available_gateways[ $data['payment_method'] ] ) ? $available_gateways[ $data['payment_method'] ]  : $data['payment_method'] );

        $order->set_payment_method('stripe_cc');


        $order->set_shipping_total( $cart->get_shipping_total() );
        $order->set_discount_total( $cart->get_discount_total() );
        $order->set_discount_tax( $cart->get_discount_tax() );
        $order->set_cart_tax( $cart->get_cart_contents_tax() + $cart->get_fee_tax() );
        $order->set_shipping_tax( $cart->get_shipping_tax() );
        $order->set_total( $cart->get_total( 'edit' ) );
        $order->payment_complete();

        $checkout->create_order_line_items( $order, $cart );
        $checkout->create_order_fee_lines( $order, $cart );
        $checkout->create_order_shipping_lines( $order, WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ), WC()->shipping->get_packages() );
        $checkout->create_order_tax_lines( $order, $cart );
        $checkout->create_order_coupon_lines( $order, $cart );


   
       // $installed_payment_methods = WC()->payment_gateways->payment_gateways();
        //print_r( $installed_payment_methods );

     //   echo "string methoname".$methoname;
    
        /**
         * Action hook to adjust order before save.
         * @since 3.0.0
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', $order, $data );


        // Save the order.
        $order_id = $order->save();
        
        do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', $order_id, $data );

        
        do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', $order_id, $data );

        echo 'Order Created Successfullt: ID'.$order_id.'.' ;
    }
    die();
}
```

How can I complete a payment after completing the order?

Comment: This is a nice attempt! + 1… But you should need to call first something similar to [`WC_Checkout` `process_checkout()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.9.2/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L1104-L1196) (which first validate order, then call `create_order()` method process user data too and finally process payment after). Things are much more complicated than you thought.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, First of all, thank you for your good response, Can you please help me how can I set or call the process_checkout method in my existing code? I have tried to put but not working.

Comment: Sorry but this is something advanced and too broad for StackOverFlow… I have never did that yet… But I know enough about WooCommerce logic to see what was wrong with your code.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for this. Do you have any idea about how can we process orders with a multi-step checkout form without using any plugin?

Comment: Without ajax, If I will try to use multi-step checkout form

Comment: All multisteps use jQuery, so when everything is correct you just need to trigger 'submit()'. You should ask a new question providing all related code, or at least a something testable.